# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate

Tags: java

Why does the following happen and how can I fix it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate
    at org.jsoup.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:47)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:57)
    at linksfind.main(linksfind.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.Validate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that the class `org.apache.commons.lang.Validate` is missing in the runtime classpath. You just have to add the JAR file containing the class to the runtime classpath. It's the [Apache Commons Lang JAR file](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi). This is also explicitly mentioned at the current Jsoup download page.

Assuming that you're launching it using plain vanilla `java.exe` like as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460073/which-packages-must-be-imported), then do so:

```
java -cp .;/path/to/jsoup.jar;/path/to/commons-lang.jar com.example.YourClass
```

---

Note that the Jsoup author has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452467/do-external-libraries-make-apps-slower/3453515#3453515) to remove the Commons Lang dependency in the next Jsoup release.

> The next release of jsoup will not require Apache Commons-Lang or any other external dependencies, which brings down the jar size to around 115K.

Jsoup 1.3.1 is the first version which does not require Apache Commons Lang anymore.

Comment: I've just released jsoup 1.3.1 which no longer depends on Apache Commons-Lang (or any other libs).

Comment: @BalusC, http://www.trieuvan.com/apache/commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.5-bin.zip links to 404...

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the [Apache Commons/Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and make sure it's included in `CLASSPATH` (or if using IDE, make sure that all required libraries are included in the build configuration).

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Platform Environment/PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need the jar file in your classpath.
From google it could be commons-lang-2.4.jar or similar

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Jar from
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4