# Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate

Tags: java, google-app-engine

in my google app engine project Log section write out

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate...
```

I have read [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468027/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-lang-validate) and did as it is written. But its' had no effect and my server is not working

Comment: Add the Apache Commons Lang JAR to your CLASSPATH.  It's either not in your project or the JVM can't find it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If Eclipse, are you using the Google APP plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says, No class def found. That mean the JVM is not able to load the said class file. You will have to make sure that this class is available in the `commons-lang` project.

Validate that you have `commons-lang-<>.jar` is added to class path of your project configuration. If not please do add the said jar file in the class path.