# Add 6 hours to the server EDT timezone

Tags: java

I am trying to adjust the Server time to my local time by adding 6 hours to the EDT Server time. I tried it with the use of `DateUtils` but I am getting this error below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils

**Code:**

```
String sql = "SELECT r.route "
        + "FROM routes AS r "
        + "JOIN arrivaltimes AS a ON a.route_id = r.route_id "
        + "JOIN stops as s on a.stop_id = s.stop_id "
        + "WHERE a.weekday = ?  "
        + "AND arrivaltime BETWEEN ? - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND ? + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE "
        + "AND s.name = ?";

PreparedStatement preparedTime = con.prepareStatement(sql);

Date d1 = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String serverTime = df.format(d1);
java.sql.Time time = null;
try {
    time = new java.sql.Time(df.parse(serverTime).getTime());

    Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(time, 6);
    System.out.println(newDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could you check if DateUtils is in your classpath?

Comment: I have this package `import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;` I have already imported the jar.

Comment: This error comes when the classloader couldn't find the class at runtime. I think somehow the jar is not in runtime classpath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468027/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-lang-validate)

Comment: I have this jar `commons-lang-2.3` in my libraries (Java build path)

Comment: The problem is completely different than what the title implies. The tag `[java-time]` refers to the JSR-310/Java 8 API that you are not using in the existing post. Besides, why do you disturb the server time, by the way?

Comment: @Tiny: Thanks  I have deleted it.  I want to Change the Server time since I have on `openshift` a  `arrivalTimes` table with `arrivaleTime` coloumn so I have to adjust the Server time to get the result depends on my timezone. and not the Server timezone.

Comment: Date/time should always be stored into a database using a standard zone like UTC which is then to be represented according to the client's zone upon retrieval (while fetching the data from the associated database and displaying it to the client).